# How to create a Task which always yields?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

In contrast to `Task.Wait()` or `Task.Result`, `await`’ing a `Task` in C# 5 prevents the thread which executes the wait from lying fallow. Instead, the method using the `await` keyword needs to be `async` so that the call of `await` just makes the method to return a new task which represents the execution of the `async` method.

But when the `await`’ed `Task` completes before the `async` method has received CPU time again, the `await` recognizes the `Task` as finished and thus the `async` method will return the `Task` object only at a later time. In some cases this would be later than acceptable because it probably is a common mistake that a developer assumes the `await`’ing always defers the subsequent statements in his `async` method.

The mistaken `async` method’s structure could look like the following:

```
async Task doSthAsync()
{
    var a = await getSthAsync();

    // perform a long operation
}
```

Then sometimes `doSthAsync()` will return the `Task` only after a long time.

I know it should rather be written like this:

```
async Task doSthAsync()
{
    var a = await getSthAsync();

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // perform a long operation
    };
}
```

... or that:

```
async Task doSthAsync()
{
    var a = await getSthAsync();
    await Task.Yield();

    // perform a long operation
}
```

But I do not find the last two patterns pretty and want to prevent the mistake to occur. I am developing a framework which provides `getSthAsync` and the first structure shall be common. So `getSthAsync` should return an Awaitable which always yields like the `YieldAwaitable` returned by `Task.Yield()` does.

Unfortunately most features provided by the Task Parallel Library like `Task.WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task> tasks)` only operate on `Task`s so the result of `getSthAsync` should be a `Task`.

So is it possible to return a `Task` which always yields?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the consumer of an async method shouldn't assume it will "yield" as that's nothing to do with it being async. If the consumer needs to make sure there's an offload to another thread they should use `Task.Run` to enforce that.

Second of all, I don't see how using `Task.Run`, or `Task.Yield` is problematic as it's used inside an async method which returns a `Task` and not a `YieldAwaitable`.

If you want to create a `Task` that behaves like `YieldAwaitable` you can just use `Task.Yield` inside an async method:

```
async Task Yield()
{
    await Task.Yield();
}
```

Edit:

As was mentioned in the comments, this has a race condition where it may not always yield. This race condition is inherent with how `Task` and `TaskAwaiter` are implemented. To avoid that you can create your own `Task` and `TaskAwaiter`:

```
public class YieldTask : Task
{
    public YieldTask() : base(() => {})
    {
        Start(TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    public new TaskAwaiterWrapper GetAwaiter() => new TaskAwaiterWrapper(base.GetAwaiter());
}

public struct TaskAwaiterWrapper : INotifyCompletion
{
    private TaskAwaiter _taskAwaiter;

    public TaskAwaiterWrapper(TaskAwaiter taskAwaiter)
    {
        _taskAwaiter = taskAwaiter;
    }

    public bool IsCompleted => false;
    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation) => _taskAwaiter.OnCompleted(continuation);
    public void GetResult() => _taskAwaiter.GetResult();
}
```

This will create a task that **always** yields because `IsCompleted` **always** returns false. It can be used like this:

```
public static readonly YieldTask YieldTask = new YieldTask();

private static async Task MainAsync()
{
    await YieldTask;
    // something
}
```

Note: I highly discourage anyone from actually doing this kind of thing.

Comment: The usage is not problematic; the problem is, that it needs to be done (in my opinion).

Comment: Or just `Task.Run(() => { })`. That should work, too.

Comment: @usr true, only it has a race condition as the task may manage to complete before `IsCompleted` is checked.

Comment: True. But that also is true for your Yield wrapper I think. It overloads my brain right now. I think the TCS.Task returned by Yield() can be marked completed before Yield() returns.

Comment: ...Then your answer would be wrong. Can anyone confirm this race condition exists?

Comment: @ominug it does. It will always will, unless you complete the task yourself, or use a custom task.

Comment: @ominug I've edited the answer showing how to create a task that **always** yields.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a polished version of [i3arnon's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158950/how-to-create-a-task-which-always-yields/32159027#32159027) `YieldTask`:

```
public class YieldTask : Task
{
    public YieldTask() : base(() => { },
        TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously)
        => RunSynchronously();

    public new YieldAwaitable.YieldAwaiter GetAwaiter()
        => default;

    public new YieldAwaitable ConfigureAwait(bool continueOnCapturedContext)
    {
        if (!continueOnCapturedContext) throw new NotSupportedException();
        return default;
    }
}
```

The `YieldTask` is immediately completed upon creation, but its awaiter says otherwise. The `GetAwaiter().IsCompleted` always returns `false`. This mischief makes the `await` operator to trigger the desirable asynchronous switch, every time it awaits this task. Actually creating multiple `YieldTask` instances is redundant. A singleton would work just as well.

There is a problem with this approach though. The underlying methods of the `Task` class are not virtual, and hiding them with the [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) modifier means that polymorphism doesn't work. If you store a `YieldTask` instance to a `Task` variable, you'll get the default task behavior. This is a considerable drawback for my use case, but I can't see any solution around it.