# How to convert a YieldAwaitable to a Task

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

The built-in [`Task.Yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield) method returns a [`YieldAwaitable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.yieldawaitable). I would like a method with similar semantics that returns a `Task`. Is there a simple/general way to convert this awaitable to a `Task`, other than wrapping it in my own asynchronous wrapper?

```
public static async Task YieldAsync()
{
    await Task.Yield();
}
```

---

**Update:** The above implementation is incorrect. The resulting task behaves differently than the wrapped awaitable.

Comment: Does it help? [How to create a Task which always yields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158950/how-to-create-a-task-which-always-yields)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski yes, my question is a duplicate of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158950/how-to-create-a-task-which-always-yields) question. Thanks for finding it!